# Play a song with time duration input

Tags: avfoundation

I would like to play a song with time duration from A seconds to B seconds in iOS SDK. However, I still have not found out a  way to implement this.

Does anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use AVAudioPlayer

```
- (void) playPauseButtonSelector: (UIButton*) sender
{
if (!_isPlaying)
{
    //play song
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [_audioPlayer setCurrentTime:_startingTime];

    [_audioPlayer play];

    _isPlaying = YES;
}
else
{
    //pause action
    [_audioPlayer pause];
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
    _isPlaying = NO;
}
}
```

In the function updateTime, comparing the currentTime of audioPlayer with ending point to stop playing

```
- (void) updateTime: (NSTimer*) time
{

if (_audioPlayer.currentTime >= _endingTime)
{
    //pause
    [self playPauseButtonSelector:nil];
}

}
```